# Homebrew command-line to display a formula's homepage

Tags: command-line, homebrew

I can open the homepage for a [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) formula by running the command-line:

`brew home <formula>`

and for a Homebrew Cask by running the following command-line:

`brew home --cask <cask>`

How can I see just the homepage URL on the command-line?

How do I open the hyperlink in a specific Web-browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homepage URL is a part of the output of `brew info FORMULA`, so you can run:

```
brew info FORMULA | grep -E '^https?:'
```

to extract just the link to the homepage. This also allows to run:

```
open -a Firefox.app "$(brew info FORMULA | grep -E '^https?:')"
```

to open the link in Firefox.app.

The respective command-lines for Homebrew Cask are:

```
brew info --cask CASK | grep -E '^https?:'
```

and

```
open -a Firefox.app "$(brew info --cask CASK | grep -E '^https?:')"
```

Comment: @NimeshNeema Not sure it needs `-E` here, works without as well.

Comment: That's really strange. I originally tried without `-E` but it didn't appear to work. I read though the man page and tried adding support for extended regular expression and it worked. I am using the Apple installed `grep` in macOS 10.15.4 with version `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`. Additionally, I also have Xcode Command Line Tools installed.

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks for spotting this. So much for making a "small" change when copying the working solution from Terminal into the browser...